# Finding Local IP via Socket Creation / getsockname

Tags: c++, sockets, ip-address, ip

I need to get the IP address of a system within C++. I followed the logic and advice of another comment on here and created a socket and then utilized getsockname to determine the IP address which the socket is bound to.

However, this doesn't appear to work (code below). I'm receiving an invalid IP address (58.etc) when I should be receiving a 128.etc

Any ideas?

```
   string Routes::systemIP(){

    // basic setup
    int sockfd;
    char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    sockaddr* sa;
    socklen_t* sl;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo("4.2.2.1", "80", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return "1";
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: socket");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "talker: failed to bind socket\n");
        return "2";
    }

    // get information on the local IP from the socket we created
    getsockname(sockfd, sa, sl);

    // convert the sockaddr to a sockaddr_in via casting
    struct sockaddr_in *sa_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)sa;

    // get the IP from the sockaddr_in and print it
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa_ipv4->sin_addr.s_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    // return the IP
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already contains the hint: `failed to bind socket`. But you cut the part of the code that attempts connecting out (did you copy from Stevens UnP?). The socket is not connected to anything, so the network stack has not assigned the local address to it yet.

Once you connect the socket the kernel has to select the local address for it according to the routing table. At that point `getsockname(2)` will work as expected.

Comment: There is no connection required here -- this is the startup of a structure for a UDP datagram connection. I had assumed that the creation of the socket would assign a local address, apparently not?

Comment: `connect(2)` works on UDP sockets too. It's actually pretty neat. If you have the UnP book - read about connected UDP sockets.  

To answer your question - no, creating a socket just reserves a file descriptor, it does not bind it to any address.

Comment: I was actually looking at Beej's Guide to network programming for the socket structure.

Comment: That's a good source too, but get the latest edition of UnP (3rd now) anyway - it's a very good investment, you'll keep getting back to it all the time. I know I do.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to allocate a socket to get the machine's available IP addresses.  You can use the socket API gethostname() and gethostbyname() functions instead.  Or, on Windows, you can alternatively use the Win32 API GetAdaptersInfo() or GetAdaptersAddresses() function instead.

Comment: This will give me all of the machines IP addresses though, correct? I need to know that the IP address which I have selected is the IP which communication occurs on with the remote system selected (in this case, 4.2.2.1). 

Is there some way to filter all of the IP addresses easily?

Comment: Then you must connect to the target machine, and then call getsockname on the socket after it's connected

Comment: Connecting is the most accurate.  However, if you do not want to waste a connection, the Win32 API has GetBestInterface/Ex() functions (but they only work with IPv4).

Comment: Is there a linux equivalent of GetBestInterface?

Comment: I'm not a Linux developer, so I have no clue, sorry.

Comment: gethostname and gethostbyname will not return the machine's IP addresses.  They will return the hostname, and the address(es) to which that hostname resolves.  It is very possible for a machine to (a) be configured such that its name does not resolve to an IP, or (b) be configured such that its name resolves to multiple IPs, only one of which belongs to that machine.

Comment: @Chris: what you describe may be true, but it is not common. Using the `gethostname`/`gethostbyname` combo is a common cross-platform approach to getting the local IPs, as it usually only returns local IPs. Nevertheless, it is good to know.

Comment: @remy: "common" is a relative term; the configurations I describe do happen, especially (a).  (b) is fairly common in large-scale deployments, e.g., datacenters.  Try doing an nslookup/dig for www.google.com (or any other front-facing hostname).  Even if it's not common enough, your testing ought to include production code that guards against the possibility.  I've seen enough production code using your technique that eventually fails in mysterious ways.